# Configurar Servidor IIS para red local

Tags: iis

tardes, noches.

Estoy configurando un sitio en IIS para entrar desde otros equipos en la misma red desde la computadora **A**. No tengo problema en entrar desde la computadora **B** si escribo la dirección IP y el puerto de la computadora **A** en la computadora **B**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si trato de escribir un Host Name "evaluacion" ya no es posible accesar. Ya modifique el archivo hosts en "../etc".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el archivo hosts ya puse la IP con y sin puerto y no funciona de ninguna manera ¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?